# Windowing a speech signal correctly

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft, speech-recognition, speech

I'm applying a Hamming window to a speech signal in order to perform features extraction of the audio sound.

The way I'm splitting the signal into frames is correct? Should I use a window overlap?

> Here's my attempt using MATLAB:

```
clear
close all

[data,fs] = audioread('speech_demo.wav');

timeWindow   = 20e-3;
lengthWindow = round(timeWindow*fs); % number of samples per window

L       = lengthWindow;
w_start = 0;
w_end   = lengthWindow;
j = 1;
for k = 1:round(length(data)/lengthWindow)

    x = w_start:w_end-1;
    hold on
    plot(x,hann(lengthWindow),'r:');
    plot(x,data(x+1),'k.-')
    plot(x,data(x+1).*hamming(lengthWindow),'m.-')
    wSignal(j:L*k,:) = data(x+1).*hamming(lengthWindow);

    w_start = w_start + L;
    w_end   = w_start + L;
    j       = L*k+1;

end
set(gcf,'color','w')
```

The plot of the signals and the windows:
[image]

A zoom in:
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Typically if you are using a Hamming function over a window, it is better to use an overlapping window. Do you have access to the DSP toolbox in Matlab? If Yes, you can use the function `buffer` to achieve your goal without using for loops.

Comment: @kedarps I do have access to the DSP toolbox. How can I use the function buffer to avoid for loops?

Comment: Use [`buffer`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/buffer.html), which will convert your signal into a matrix of dataframes. You can specify the number of samples you wish to overlap. Now use your `hamming` window with [`bsxfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to multiple the window to each dataframe in the matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my comment on using `buffer` and `bsxfun`. Consider following code,

```
[y,Fs] = audioread('someAudioFile.wav');

timeWindow   = 20e-3;
lengthWindow = round(timeWindow*Fs); % number of samples per window

% third argument specifies the number of overlapping samples
yBuffer = buffer(y, lengthWindow, round(lengthWindow*0.2));
hammWin = hamming(lengthWindow);

yBufferWindowed = bsxfun(@times, yBuffer, hammWin);
```

Comment: thank you soon much. It's way easier that way. yBufferWindowed is a matrix [lW x nW]
where lW is the length window and nW is the number of windows, which corresponds to length(y)/lengthWindow. 

To get a single vector I'm thinking about using the reshape function: y = reshape(yBufferWindowed, lengthWindow*nW); 

Is that right?

Comment: Yes you can certainly use reshape, but your signal length will not be the same as the original signal since their were windowed segments. If you wish to extract features, you can extract them from the buffered signal itself.